# Maven. Moving from library to maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, wildfly

I'm trying to move my dummy project to maven. Previously I was using for a wildfly 10 a jboss-client.jar. Now I would like to get the same functionality from maven repository. Readme advises using following dependencies:

```
     </dependency>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

However, I get this errors.

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:72)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:61)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: try if adding this dependency helps https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jboss-remote-naming/2.0.5.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do a maven build clean install and see if build is able to finish successfully.
2. Do maven>Update project.
3. I use eclipse as IDE in which I have an open type button (ctrl + shift + t). Open that and search the class name: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory. If it doesn't show up, you have a problem in your dependencies (pom.xml doesn't have all the required packages).
4. Additionally, if you are using tcServer or any other server, try clearing off all the pre-built files (.class files and everything) re-publish the project.
5. If all the above mentioned steps are successful and still you are not able to resolve the error, I guess cleaning your local .m2 folder and re-building everything from scratch might help.

These are general steps that I follow to resolve almost every error that comes from maven for me.

Also, make sure jboss-client jar is present in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your project in your IDE or by command line:

**IDE:**

- Maven > Update project

**Command line:**

```
mvn clean install
```

If this don't work, delete your artifacts from your .m2 folder and artifacts folders.